# Windows 10 "Other User" option in login screen

Tags: windows-10, office365, azure

I need to log in to windows 10 with a user not presented at the login screen. There is no option to select another user. We're using Office 365 to administrate users without the ability to create gpo's. I have resetted the password of one user but the new password does not work on windows.

Is there a way to enable this feature or am I missing something?

Comment: Does the other account belong to the Users group when running `lusrmgr.msc`?

Comment: I would like to be able do that too... or have a keyboard shortcut to show user/password textboxes (the "other" login screen...)